# .htaccess Get variable as subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have a site that I'm manually translating. The normal version is in English and the translated version is in Spanish.

The translated version is accessible through http://example.com/file.php?language=es (es for espanol)
I want the URL after the domain to be unaltered by the change in translation, so I'm  trying to use http://es.example.com/ instead.

This is the current state of my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.site$
RewriteRule home/$ /index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule contact-us/$ /contact-us.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule our-location/$ /our-location.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule gallery/$ /gallery.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /user.php?display_name=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^es\.example\.site$
RewriteRule home/$ /index.php?language=es [L,QSA]
RewriteRule contact-us/$ /contact-us.php?language=es [L,QSA]
RewriteRule our-location/$ /our-location.php?language=es [L,QSA]
RewriteRule gallery/$ /gallery.php?language=es [L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /user.php?language=es&display_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The first set of rules under !^example.site$ all override the rules from under !^es.example.site$, so when I access the pages with or without the "es" subdomain, I'm getting the English version either way. If I place the subdomain rules (and rewrite condition) above the non-subdomain rules then the same thing happens except the site is only translated in Spanish.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

The fixed rules, thanks to the help of @hjpotter92

```
RewriteRule ^home/?$ /index.php [NC,QSA,S=3]
RewriteRule ^(contact-us|our-location|gallery)/?$ /$1.php [NC,QSA,S=2]
RewriteRule ^(?!user\.php).*/$ /user.php?display_name=$0 [NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es\.example\.site$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !language=es [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0?language=es [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably trying to achieve this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^home/?$ /index.php [NC,QSA,S=3]
RewriteRule ^(contact-us|our-location|gallery)/?$ /$1.php [NC,QSA,S=2]
RewriteRule ^(?!user\.php).*/$ /user.php?display_name=$0 [NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !language=es [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0?language=es [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What a speedy and efficient answer! The revisions for the non-subdomain rules work perfectly. But the subdomain rules are throwing up 500 internal server errors for some reason.

Comment: Sure. I'm getting repeat lines of this: "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."

Comment: @awl19 Updated the rules again. Please check

Comment: Made the changes. No more errors and using the subdomain is properly using the get variable, but for whatever reason the "sub-folder" proceeding the domain is using the user.php rule instead of the rule specified. In other words, http://es.example.com/home/ is really coming out to something like http://example.com/user.php?display_name=home&language=es instead of http://example.com/index.php?language=es

Comment: @awl19 increment the values of each `S=` in the rule by _1_. I'll run some tests on my own server as well. BTW, which apache version are you using?

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much for your help =D Do you mind explaining or linking to an article about what the "S=" bit does?